# glDrawElements Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently trying to draw an object using VBOs.
In the Cube-Class I came up with to test the functionality of VBOs, I create the VBOs like this:

```
//Vertex
glGenBuffers(1, &m_bufVertex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufVertex);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*4*3*sizeof(GLfloat), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//TexCoord
glGenBuffers(1, &m_bufTexCoord);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufTexCoord);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*4*2*sizeof(GLfloat), texcoord_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
//Index
glGenBuffers(1,&m_bufIndex);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,m_bufIndex);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,24*sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I already double checked if the data is in the buffers e.g. like this (the vertex buffer is binded at that time):

```
GLfloat* test = (GLfloat *) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6*4*3; i++)
    cout << "Value " << i << " = " << test[i] << endl;
```

So the data is where it is supposed to be, so the problem seems to lie within the Render-Function. The Segmentation-Error happens when glDrawElements() or glDrawArrays() is called.
Here is the code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
// some translation, currently fixed, just testing code
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -200.0f);
glRotatef(30.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
glRotatef(30.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
glRotatef(30.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
// enable client states
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
// set pointers
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufVertex);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufTexCoord);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_bufIndex);
// just error check to see if something went wrong previously
GLenum err = glGetError();
if (GL_NO_ERROR != err)
    cout << "GL: " << err << " - " << gluErrorString(err) << endl;
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
// disable state and pop matrix
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glPopMatrix();
```

I assume I am using the pointers not right or glDrawElements(), but I don't know what.
Some more informations:
The code is compiled on MacOSX Lion (OpenGL2.1) using the GNU-toolchain and GLEW.

EDIT:

```
GLfloat vertex_data[6*4*3] = {-m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize,  m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize,  m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        -m_fSize, -m_fSize, m_fSize,
                        -m_fSize,  m_fSize, m_fSize,
                         m_fSize,  m_fSize, m_fSize,
                         m_fSize, -m_fSize, m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize,  m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize,  m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize, -m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize,  m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize,  m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, -m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize, -m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                       -m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, -m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, -m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                        -m_fSize, m_fSize,  m_fSize,
                        -m_fSize, m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                         m_fSize, m_fSize, -m_fSize,
                        m_fSize, m_fSize,  m_fSize};
 GLfloat texcoord_data[6*4*2] = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
                                0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
GLuint indices[24] = {0,1,2,3,
                     4,5,6,7,
                     8,9,10,11,
                     12,13,14,15,
                     16,17,18,19,
                     20,21,22,23};
```

I know am defining every vertex instead of just 8...

EDIT2:
The makefile:

```
OUT = bin/test
CC = g++
INCDIR = inc
OBJDIR = obj
SRCDIR = src
INC = -I$(INCDIR) -I/opt/local/include
LIBS = -L/opt/local/lib -lGLEW -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -framework AGL -framework OpenGL -framework Foundation

_OBJS = Main.o \
    Timer.o \
    Cube.o \
    chrono.o process_cpu_clocks.o thread_clock.o error_code.o

OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJS))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
$(CC) -c $(INC) -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) 


$(OUT): $(OBJS)
$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
strip $(OUT)

clean:
rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o $(OUT)
```

Comment: You haven't shown us anything at all about `m_bufVertex` or `m_bufTexCoord`.

Comment: The output in the terminal window when binding and mapping the buffers are fine, so the data must be on the gpu side where it is supposed to be. When I break right before the glDrawElements call using the GL Profiler, the VBOs are all setup and size etc is alright. m_bufVertex, m_bufTExCoord are member variables of that class and everything is happining in member functions so everything is in scope.

Comment: It's looking good at the first glance. Just to be sure, clean the project and rebuild it from scratch. Then try to back up a bit to flush out the error: draw only one quad, don't use VBOs, etc.

Comment: Rebuilding doesn't help, when I am commenting out the glDrawElements()-Call or disable that the function is called in the GL Profiler, no error accures. When I render the same data with the same matrix calls intermediate it works fine.

Comment: I am starting to think that may be a mac specific problem using glew on macosx lion. Any known issues with that?

Comment: What library are you using to create your window? And what commands do you use to compile it?

Comment: I am using the SFML(2.0) library for window creation GLEW for rendering. I'll add the build commands in the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. The problem is that SFML internally uses 
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY) and 
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
so you need to disable those if you don't use them yourself.

Or you could use sf::Window instead of sf::RenderWindow, since it doesn't set any OpenGL state internally, which I chose to do.

[Post on the SFML forum with this exact problem](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=44842)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you left a vertex array enabled in a previous draw? For example, if you do something like this:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(...);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glNormalPointer(...);
glDrawElements(...); // draw first object

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(...);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(...);
glDrawElements(...); // draw second object
```

The second glDrawElements could crash because the normal array is still enabled but probably not the right size for the second draw.

Comment: Thanks alot, the GL_COLOR_ARRAY was enabled, I disabled it after the window initialisation and now it works, a bit odd, so there must be something wrong about the sfml renderwindow-class...